# Match sub-rule backwards in ANTLR4 parser

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I have a portion of an ANTLR4 rule that I'd like to parse backwards.  I suspect that's not the real solution, so there's likely something I'm missing.

The crux of my problem is that there's a part in the middle of my expression that I'd like to extract.  However, this part has some (defined) suffixes that I would really like to extract separately, if possible.  These suffixes can be separated by a comma or not; the grammar works fine with the comma, but if the comma is missing, it takes the entire part as `unknown`, even if the suffixes are present.

I've pared down my grammar into a small example, visible at the bottom of this post.

Given the string `why hello, x y z foo bar baz blah blah blah, goodbye!`, my grammar will parse `x y z foo bar baz` as a `phrase`.  I would like to match `x y z` as `unknown` and `foo bar baz` as suffixes.  If there is a comma (`x y z, foo bar baz`), it works:
[image: tree generated with comma]

However, if there is no comma, it takes the entire `x y z foo bar baz` (as well as some of the text after) as `unknown`:
[image: tree generated with no comma]

I tried changing `unknown` to be nongreedy (`+?`), but that is undesirable as well, consuming only one token for `phrase`:
[image: tree generated with no comma and nongreedy unknown]

**Is there a way to force the `phrase` rule to try matching suffixes from the right first before falling back to `unknown`?**

Another way to put it: is there a way to have `unknown` match anything *except* when it *ends* with one or more suffixes?  (The suffixes can appear in the text as long as they're not at the end)

Example grammar:

```
grammar Example;

// parse tree root
exampleExpression : ignored HELLO separator phrase separator? unknown separator? GOODBYE ignored;

// what I want to match
phrase : unknown (COMMA? suffix+)*;

// convenience rule for swaths of tokens to be ignored (e.g. at the beginning and end)
ignored : (unknown | separator)*;

// roll up unknown tokens under one rule
unknown : (~(PERIOD | COMMA | PIPE | BULLET | SP_SEP_DASH))+;
separator : PERIOD | COMMA | PIPE | BULLET | SP_SEP_DASH;

// the pre-defined suffixes
suffix : FOO | BAR | BAZ;

/* TOKENS */

HELLO : 'hello';
GOODBYE : 'goodbye';
FOO : 'foo';
BAR : 'bar';
BAZ : 'baz';

/* FRAGMENTS */

fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
fragment DASH : '-';

/* REMAINING TOKENS */

LPAREN : '(' ;
RPAREN : ')' ;
COMMA : ',';
PERIOD : '.';
PIPE : '|';
BULLET : '\u00B7' | '\u2219' | '\u22c5';
SP_SEP_DASH : SP DASH SP;

SP : [ \u000B\t\r\n] -> channel(HIDDEN);

NUMBER : ([0] | [1-9] DIGIT*) ('.' DIGIT+)?;
WORD : [A-Za-z] [A-Za-z-]*;

// catch-all
OTHER : .;
```

Comment: Wild guess: `phrase : unknown COMMA? (suffix+)*;` instead of `phrase : unknown (COMMA? suffix+)*;`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Surely `(suffix+)*` is the same as `suffix*`, but I suppose what is really wanted is `suffix+`, possibly with interspersed COMMAs. IOW: `COMMA? (suffix+ COMMA)* suffix+`. But I don't think that is the fundamental problem here.

Comment: My point was that `phrase` only appears to accept `suffix` if `COMMA` is also present.

Comment: Right, `phrase` has `(COMMA? suffix+)*` to support phrases like `x y z, foo, bar, baz`.  Suffixes are not always present, though, hence `*` instead of `+`.  FWIW, if I were to ignore the multiple-comma case, `unknown COMMA? suffix*` exhibits the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

The question says:

> Another way to put it: is there a way to have unknown match anything except when it ends with one or more suffixes? (**The suffixes can appear in the text** as long as they're not at the end)

But previously, a parse of `unknown` with internal suffixes was rejected:

> However, if there is no comma, it takes the entire x y z foo bar baz (as well as some of the text after) as unknown

That seems inconsistent.

From the example, it seems like you are trying to do natural language parsing; ANTLR, whatever its virtues, is probably not a good tool for that. But that might just be a chimera based on your simplification.

In any event, the answer to your original question -- "is it possible to define a non-terminal as any sequence of tokens which don't end with one or more tokens from a suffix class" is "yes, that can be written as a context-free-grammar". Without getting into ANTLR specifics, here's a simple CFG:

```
wordlist: /* empty */ | wordlist non_suffix | wordlist suffix_list non_suffix ;
suffix_list: suffix | suffix_list suffix ;
```

Comment: When I said "However, if there is no comma, it takes the entire x y z foo bar baz (as well as some of the text after) as unknown," I meant that that's what's happening, though undesired.  In that case, I would have expected `unknown` `suffixes` `unknown`.  I can see how that might be difficult to figure out, though, unless it was parsed backwards somehow (or that was my thinking).

Thanks for your suggested CFG.  I will mess around with that as a starting point.

Comment: @NickAldwin: I understood that. But in your requirements, you say that unknown can contain suffixes if they are not at the end (highlighted in my quote). Then you complain that your grammar is accepting unknown with suffixes which are not at the end. That's the inconsistency. If you want suffixes to be parsed as suffixes regardless of where they occur, the grammar is trivial. If you have other expectations, you need to be more precise about them.

Comment: Understood, there's no way for the parser to understand the difference between `unknown` `suffixes` `unknown` and `unknown(with suffixes in the middle)`.

Comment: @NickAldwin: It's not just the parser which doesn't understand that difference. *I* don't understand the difference :)